# How to find data on the most-streamed songs of all time on Spotify, globally?

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I'm working on a projected with Spotify data and I need a list of the most-streamed songs of all time on Spotify. (Not my own listening history, but the global stream counts) This information should be out there, because songs on Spotify publicly display their stream count, but there's no actual list of the most-streamed songs beyond the first 100 or 200. I want to be able to get as many songs as I want, or at least 1000 or 2000. I'm using python for this but could use something else if necessary. I've found SpotiPy, but it doesn't seem to have this capability as far as I can tell.

I looked for answers online but found nothing. And I've emailed Spotify and even gotten responses, but their responses weren't at all helpful. They either didn't understand my question or redirected me to their research and developer sites which don't see to have what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Spotipy and Spotify API do not provide functionality for this *directly*, but you can retrieve all the songs from the public playlist called "Spotifys Most Played All Time [Updated Weekly] | Most Streamed  | Top Played", which has playlist_id of `2YRe7HRKNRvXdJBp9nXFza`. Using this ID, and the following code with Spotipy:

```py
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials

client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id='YOUR_CLIENT_ID', client_secret='YOUR_SECRET')
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)

# playlist ID of the top streamed songs
playlist_id = '2YRe7HRKNRvXdJBp9nXFza'

# get tracks
results = sp.playlist_tracks(playlist_id)

# get track name and artist
tracks = results['items']
for track in tracks:
    track_name = track['track']['name']
    artist_name = track['track']['artists'][0]['name']
    print(f"{track_name} by {artist_name}")
```

This returns the top 50 streamed songs:

[image]

Which can be cross referenced with the [top streamed Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Spotify_streaming_records) to show that the list is correct. It may vary slightly intra-weekly since the playlist is updated weekly (likely manually), but should generally be right.

Alternatively, if you want thousands of songs, you could scrape [this site](https://kworb.net/spotify/songs.html) which provides a list using the following beautifulsoup module:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://kworb.net/spotify/songs.html'

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

rows = soup.find_all('tr')

song_list = []
for row in rows:
    div = row.find('div')  
    if div: 
        div_text = div.text  
        song_list.append(div_text)

print(song_list)
```

This returns the top 2500 most streamed songs.